# Web interface tool for debian repository?

Tags: web-applications, debian, packaging

What is the web interface tool that Debian or Ubuntu use for publicizing their custom repositories on the web?

Like [packages.debian.org](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages)

Is such tool open sourced, so that it could be re-used for a custom repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts that manage the archive are open source, they're in a debian package called dak. I don't think this includes the web pages, but I'm not sure. I'd suggest emailling ftpmaster@debian.org or debian-www@lists.debian.org and asking.

Parsing the packages file is indeed very straightforward but there's still a lot of work to make a nice set of web pages from it so it would be worth seeing if you can get hold of what debian use.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need something to parse the Packages file, no? [Example Packages file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ubuntu/dists/hardy/main/binary-i386/Packages). I've never attempted to do this before, but I cant imagine it being a horrendous task.

Edit: Well it would technically be spidering the repo to process a series of Packages files, but that wouldn't make it too much tougher.

Edit 2: Unless you specify the Packages files manually. Then it would be simple again.

Answer (score 0):

There are perl modules to parse the Packages file if you want to get at that type of information, [DPKG::Parse](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/DPKG-Parse/DPKG/Parse.pm.html) for example can do that. You could build a web page from that data similar to the URL you provided.

There are also tools in debian to create a "custom repository." Such a repository might contain your locally built packages for example or specific versions of things you want to have around. Tools that you might want to look at to do this are reprepro, apt-ftparchive, mini-dinstall, and debarchiver. I have used reprepro for personal packages and can recommend it, I have not used the others.

Debian uses a tool called dak but it is designed for a repo with thousands of packages and is poorly documented since it was designed to be used only by debian. It is not recommended for use for personal packages.

Comment: +1 for reprepro, it is quite nice once you get used to it's quirky workings. Great information here: http://www.jejik.com/articles/2006/09/setting_up_and_managing_an_apt_repository_with_reprepro/